# Getting an error message when running my ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm been staring at this project for a few days now. I'm trying to move a console app to an ASP.NET Core MVC project. It's supposed to read a Json and display it on a page. I can get the response and write it in my console app but when I copy the code over it's not working.

This is the `CardController`:

```
using Final_Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;

namespace Final_Project.Controllers
{
    public class CardController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Card()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://pokemon-tcg-card-prices.p.rapidapi.com/card?name=Arcues%20V");

            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "");
            request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "");

            var response = client.Execute(request).Content;

            //Console.WriteLine(response);

            Root cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Final_Project.Models.Root>(response);

            return View(cards);
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to deserialize it to my root class:

```
using static Final_Project.Models.CardInfo;

namespace Final_Project.Models
{
    public class Root
    {
        public List<Result>? cards { get; set; }
        public Paging? paging { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then put it into the `CardInfo` class. It's just a small screenshot of everything that's in this class.

```
public class Result
{
    public string? cardId { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public string? cardNumber { get; set; }
    public string? setNumber { get; set; }
    public string? setId { get; set; }
    public string? set { get; set; }
    public string? series { get; set; }
    public string? variant { get; set; }
    public string? superType { get; set; }

    public List<string>? types { get; set; }
    public List<string>? subTypes { get; set; }

    public string? rarity { get; set; }

    public List<string>? pokemon { get; set; }

    public string? artist { get; set; }
    public MinSoldPrice? minSoldPrice { get; set; }
    public LowSoldPrice? lowSoldPrice { get; set; }
    public SoldPrice? soldPrice { get; set; }
    public HighSoldPrice? highSoldPrice { get; set; }
    public MaxSoldPrice? maxSoldPrice { get; set; }
    public int? soldVolume { get; set; }
    public DateTime? soldLastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public MinListingPrice? minListingPrice { get; set; }
    public LowListingPrice? lowListingPrice { get; set; }
    public ListingPrice? listingPrice { get; set; }
    public HighListingPrice? highListingPrice { get; set; }
    public MaxListingPrice? maxListingPrice { get; set; }
    public int? listingVolume { get; set; }
    public DateTime? listingLastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public Prices? prices { get; set; }
}
```

Then it should display the data in the `Card` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Final_Project.Models.Root>

<h2>Card Info</h2>

<div> style="display: block">
    <a href="/Card/DispayCard/">Card Information</a>
</div>

<table class="table" >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Variant</th>
        <th>Card Number</th>
        <th>Rarity</th>
        <th>Card ID</th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var product in @Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><a href=/CardInfo/ViewProduct/@product.name>@product.name</a></td>
            <td>@product.name</td>
            <td>@product.variant</td>
            <td>@product.cardNumber</td>
            <td>@product.rarity</td>
            <td>@product.cardId</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I run the program I get this error message:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Final_Project.Models.Root' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any thoughts or ideas would greatly be appreciated.

I've tried to just move the variables from the `Result` class. I was able to get the dot notation to work but it still didn't display anything.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share code snippets, not images of code. Edit your question and replace the images with text. Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer.  I explain the problem with a code sample

Comment: Well, have you checked the response which you are getting from your API? Can you share what you are getting there? Based on your error message it seems that, your class defination and response doesn't matched in terms of data type. Please share your response data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in a couple of lines of code:

```
Root cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Final_Project.Models.Root>(response);
```

You are getting a single result in the previous line. A single root.

Yet in your view you expect an IEnumerable of root. Meaning many of them.

```
@model IEnumerable<Final_Project.Models.Root>
```

You need to change your view to accept a single root like this:

```
@model Final_Project.Models.Root
```

Then change your foreach like this:

```
@foreach (var product in @Model.cards)
```

Comment: I made those changes but I get a null exception.  I don't think the Json is deserializing.  Any Idea on how I can check to see if I'm getting any Json response?  In the console app I've used the break point to check the response but in MVC it doesn't seem like the breakpoint is showing any response.

Comment: @RandallSmith just place a breakpoint and check to see the string before reserializing.  The json not matching your class is a different problem

Comment: I'm definitely getting a response from the Json, but it is not deserializing it into my Root class.  My understanding is it's supposed to deserialize into the Root class then from there it passes it to the cardInfo class there it initializes all the variables in the Result class in the cardInfo class.

Comment: without the json we cannot help you deserialize it

Comment: It got figured out.  I just need to put the root in the cardIndex class and it deserialized it correctly.  Thanks.  Now on to the next headache :)